# Problema al imprimir matriz

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Tengo este método pero cuando intento realizar los cálculos no se me muestran bien en la matriz.

Yo hice otra pregunta sobre cómo podría restar por ejemplo 100 de 5 en 5 y que se mostrara esa resta.

Lo estoy usando para hacer un programa de prestamos, entonces necesito restar, un préstamo según el plazo que me dan.

Por ejemplo:

Quieren prestar 1000000 a un plazo de 6 meses.

Entonces mi programa debe dividir 1000000 por 6 y posteriormente mostrar en la `fila[i][0]` cada saldo que le toca pagar.

Adjunto una imagen como ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que quede así mismo, pero mi código no muestra nada en la columna 2 que es donde va el saldo.

Este es el código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void hojaPrestamoCalculo(int prestamo,int plazo){

        double amortizacion = ((prestamo*11.284)/100) / plazo;
        double cuotaMensual = (prestamo/plazo) + amortizacion;
        double saldo = prestamo-cuotaMensual;
        double hojaCalculoPrestamo[plazo][2];

        for(int i = 0; i < plazo; i++){
            hojaCalculoPrestamo[i][0] = cuotaMensual;
            hojaCalculoPrestamo[i][1] = amortizacion;
            for (double j=prestamo; j>=0; j=j-cuotaMensual){
                hojaCalculoPrestamo[i][2] = j;
            }
        }

        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        cout<<"        | Cuota |        | Amortizacion |       | Saldo |                   \n";
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < plazo; i++){
            cout<<"Mes :"<<i+1<<"  "<<hojaCalculoPrestamo[i][0]<<"        "<<hojaCalculoPrestamo[i][1]<<"        "<<hojaCalculoPrestamo[i][2]<<endl;
        }

        system("pause");
}

int main()
{
    hojaPrestamoCalculo(50000, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

[Aquí pueden probar el código](https://tio.run/##hZDPboQgEMbvPMWEXjRhs257VHvpqc@w8TAF3JIoWMAe1vjsLv7NbmvTCQnwMR/zm@FNc7hwPgxPSvOqFRIyZZy3EutXQlqn9AU01tI1yCU4L1JCwvMof0urSsXRvgup/XTkyuhoea4x7NfzcxEWA6U9cKM9CmMZLCnqwRh3BEIcj/CGzsAHOjkJqoRotUIGSTypY1jpW6uBllg5SdNN32wLw@ouzkkBeb5fdwxuWg9ZBnu@IEstqvRXdW/btXj/iLBk/DWouQrb5gIHOLGfcCnpCRmnV6PSUUxm2J0ZQw5dR0@U0U9TIe1ZR1/C5SvA9f2MR@57/I8qoIQP4jvn0k4SkIbhBg).

Los calculos van así:

- Amortización = ((Monto del préstamo * tasa de interés) / 100) / Plazo en meses
- Cuota mensual = (Monto del Préstamo / Plazo en meses) + Amortización
- Saldo = Monto Total del crédito – Cuota Mensual

Comment: ¿Estás segura que ese es el link? Porque parece el de una de tus otras preguntas.

Comment: El error está en que sobra el segundo for, reemplazalo por: saldo = prestamo-cuotaMensual; hojaCalculoPrestamo[i][2] = saldo;

Answer (score 0):

No podés definir una matríz usando una variable como índice. Entre los corchetes tiene que ir un valor constante.

```
double hojaCalculoPrestamo[plazo][2];
```

debería ser algo así:

```
double hojaCalculoPrestamo[12][2];
```

Comment: el problema es que la fila corresponde al número de meses del préstamo,  yo no puedo poner 12 porque que pasa si el prestamo son 3 meses o 5 meses o 7 meses, osea las filas de la matiz deben ser un valor mas dinamico

Comment: entonces es no soluciona mi problema

Comment: el problema es ese, el plazo se refiere a los meses del préstamo, entonces las filas de la matriz deben ser igual al plazo, si el plazo es 6 , la matriz debe tener 6 filas etc

Comment: c++ necesita saber de antemano cuanta memoria reservar para un contenedor al momento de definirse. Las matrices de tipo C como las que usas no pueden ser creadas con variables porque su tamaño no es variable. En su lugar deberías usar por ejemplo un objeto del tipo vector. El vector permite ir agregando datos sin límite. Es que c++ reserva más memoria de la que se está usando para que la adición de datos sea rápida. A medida que vas agregando items al vector, sa va reservando más memoria. Un vector reserva hasta en doble de espacio en memoria.

Comment: te agradezco tu respuesta, igualmente no me sirve de mucho, porque no se mucho de c++, entonces igual no puedo usar vectores, me piden mostrar las cosas en una matriz como la de la imagen de ejemplo, literalmente asi debe quedar mi tarea

Comment: entonces gracias por tu respuesta igual

Comment: la unica forma que se me ocurre para que las filas de la matriz sean dinámicas  es haciéndolo así, y lo hago así porque programo en java

Comment: Lo que podés hacer es definir una matríz con el máximo de cuotas posibles, y luego para leerla, iterar con una instrucción for solamente los primeros meses hasta completar la cantidad de meses.

Comment: Para el estándar el tamaño de los arreglos debe conocerse en tiempo de compilación. Pero sí se pueden definir arreglos de tamaño variable si el compilador lo soporta.

Comment: -Mateo ¿Que compilador habría que usar?

Comment: @Esther no podes usar vectores porque no te lo permiten o simplemente porque no sabes? Es fácil usar [vectores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Por ejemplo, si quieres crear un vector de `string` lo haces así: `vector<string> lista`. Podes recorrerlo de la misma forma que un arreglo. Para agregar elementos podes usar `push_back` o `emplace_back` que funcionan como `add` en una lista de Java. En el enlace tenés más información.

Comment: @Gabriel gcc lo soporta.

Comment: no me permiten usar vectores, al final debo imprimir todo en una matriz , solo una matriz puedo usar en mi tarea

Comment: @Mateo . ¿Por qué será que me da error de sintaxis el editor de texto sin que sepa todavía qué compilador voy a usar, cuando quiero declarar una matríz del estilo C con una variable en su índice? Uso vscode. ¿Tendré que actualizar algo?

Comment: @Gabriel creo que es porque debes configurar el compilador que vas a usar. Podrías hacer una pregunta sobre eso.